# Narita Airport Custom check for tax-free purchased items

Tags: airports, tax-refunds, nrt

I understood that I need to show my purchased item with the form attached on my passport to a custom officer at Narita Airport.

I would like to know where is this custom office located. Based on what I had googled, the custom check for this purchased item is after the check-in counter. This means I have to hand-carry it.

I would like to check-in my purchased items. Is it possible or must I hand-carry the purchased item?

Appreciate anyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary. Japan, in general, refunds the sales tax at the point of purchase provided you meet the criteria of buying over 10,000 yen that day and have a visitor visa.

You already have your tax back, so there is zero need to do anything at the airport. They have no way to know if you have it, mailed it separately, drank it, broke it, or resold it.